# How to fix "request error" from google cloud storage?

Tags: c#, api, google-cloud-storage, google-text-to-speech

I used google.cloud.storage for .mp3 files. I tried it before and it worked.
now I writed another new function that uses the existing storage function.
everything was suppose to work but I get this weird error:
"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
text-to-speach@XXXXXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to objectsound/voiceAnimals20.mp3. [403]"
I dont know what to begin with. can anybody help me?

the Ok storage function is here:

```
public static string VoiceStorage(int catId, string URL, 
Dictionary<string, int> voicesCounter)
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", 
    @"C:\wordproject-XXXXXXXXXX.json");
    // upload the image storage
    //----------------
    string voiceName;
    voiceName = "voice" + BLLcategory.GetCategoryById(catId).CategoryName 
    + voicesCounter[BLLcategory.GetCategoryById(catId).CategoryName]++ + 
    ".mp3";
    string bucketName = "XXXXXXXX";
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    using (var f = File.OpenRead(URL))
    {
        try
        {
            var res = storage.UploadObject(bucketName, voiceName, null, 
            f);
            URL = "https://storage.cloud.google.com/" + bucketName + "/" + 
            voiceName;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return URL;
}
```

the new not working function is:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (COMimageObject obj in BLLobject.GetObjects())
    {
        if(obj.VoiceURL==null)
        {
            try
            {
                string url=BLLtextToSpeach.TextToSpeach(obj.Name);
                url=BLLtextToSpeach.VoiceStorage(
                BLLimage.GetImageById(obj.ImageID).CategoryID,
                url, voicesCounter);
                BLLobject.UpdateVoiceURL(obj.ObjectId, url);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the catch happening after the line with url=BLLtextToSpeach.VoiceStorage
tnx!!

Answer (score 0):

What the error mean is that the service account of the text-to-speach api doesn't have create access on the objectsound bucket. Go to the bucket permissions and add the text-to-speach service account with storage creator rights.

Comment: tank you! but i tried add it to premissions- i pressed enale-and then what?

Comment: To add it you just need to go to the bucket, select edit bucket permission, add members, in new member insert the service account mail, will be a set of numbers/letters followed by @projectName.iam.gserviceaccount.com, (you can find it under IAM/service accounts), in role select Storage Object Creator and save. For easy/quick test you can just set your bucket as public following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public). This should do the trick for a test

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the objectsound bucket permissions?  Also please confirm that the error that you are getting is the same.

Comment: Also im now sure if you are running this from a GCP VM, if is the case you will need to set devstorage.full_control or devstorage.read_write

Comment: how to add an image to here?

Comment: and what do you mean with devstorage.full_control or devstorage.read_write?

Comment: Ok, forget the devstorage.full_control or devstorage.read_write thingy for now. Can you please doble check that you actually provided text-to-speach@texttospeach-251312.iam.gserviceaccount.com with storage.objects.create access?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the AllUsers permission should have at least create access. Setting it as objectViewer wouldn't work. Also keep in mind that AllUser setting should only be used for a quick test and isn't a recommended policy

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error:

> [403] Errors [ Message[.................iam.gserviceaccount.com does
> not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.

**you need to have permissions in your service account from the [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin) to read the buckets**

> storage.buckets.get   Read bucket metadata, excluding IAM policies.

> storage.buckets.list  List buckets in a project. Also read bucket
> metadata,

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions

The "Firebase Admin" will enable all necessary permissions.

[image]